# Error removing Xplico

Tags: package-management

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 205993 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing xplico (1.1.0) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/xplico.postrm: 23: /var/lib/dpkg/info/xplico.postrm: apache2ctl: not found
dpkg: error processing package xplico (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xplico
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Check the answers given here.. http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22217/68757

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved by editing `/var/lib/dpkg/info/xplico.postrm`.

Change the line

```
apache2ctl restart
```

to

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

then you can run `upgrade` to remove `xplico` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Apache2, then uninstall Xplico. Reinstall gnome-user-share which will reinstall the basic bits of apache2 useful for file sharing. Job done.